# Require PayPal DropDown Answer

Tags: drop-down-menu, paypal

Is there a way to REQUIRE a PayPal dropdown to be answered? Currently, my choices are 1. Select One, 2. Satchel Brown, and 3. Midnight Black. If I skip it, it accepts "Select One" as the option. What to do? Leave the first option blank? I don't want to use a default answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom button (code generated using a form) or a paypal supported button that you generated the code for in paypal?

If you are using a paypal custom created button, create a confirmation page and have it post the users choice to there. Then, using php, check to see that the users choice is one of the valid options. If it is not, then simply use the header('Location: http://www.MyWebsiteHere.com/Wherever.php?&error=Unselected') to send them back to the page and add a error message so if(isset($_GET['error'])), then echo $correspondingErrorMessage. Very simple thing if you do it like this.